# Cannot clean internal memory after failed installation

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, adb, failed-installation

I was testing a game of 300MB. I tried to deploy it from the IDE (IntelliJ in this case), but forgot to leave 600MB of space (when a file is installed via Eclipse or IntelliJ, it gets transfered into internal memory). The installation failed with an error "Not enough space on the device" and now I only have 31MB of free space.

How can I clean this as I cannot do it from the phone? Is there a way to delete this transfered file from Eclipse or ADB?

I tried removing battery, cleaning applications' cache and data, etc. All in vain.

**UPDATE**
I used ADB shell to enter the file system. This is output of `df` command

```
/dev: 86488K total, 12K used, 86476K available (block size 4096)
/data: 1428484K total, 1100000K used, 32848K available (block size 4096)
/cache: 65536K total, 36320K used, 29216K available (block size 4096)
/sqlite_stmt_journals: 4096K total, 0K used, 4096K available (block size 4096)
/system: 250880K total, 231936K used, 18944K available (block size 4096)
/lgdrm: 2816K total, 1180K used, 1636K available (block size 4096)
/sdcard: 1920704K total, 252832K used, 1667872K available (block size 32768)
```

It seems that I would have to clean /cache directory but the system does not allow me

```
$ purge /cache
purge: permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately soft reset was the only solution. If someone comes up with a better one, please say so. ADB shell was useless in this case.

Comment: If someone needs to know, this is a remote path where an app is pushed before installation: `/data/local/tmp/com.example.myapp`

Answer (score 0):

You could try a "`ADB uninstall <package>`" if you'd like to try this via the ADB.

Go to your "`<Android SDK Path>\SDK\android-sdk-<platform type>\platform-tools\`" path on your computer with a command prompt, then type the above command to remove the entire application from the handset.

Comment: `Failure` message. Also this package is not listed via adb when I use command `adb shell pm list packages`

Comment: The quickest thing would be to do a 'back to factory defaults' reset of the handset, then.

Comment: @CirrusFlyer You're right, seems this is a serious problem, that's why i always buy 1 phone for development and other for common uses lol

Answer (score 0):

I've had something similar to me and I'm trying to remember how I dealt with it.

I certainly used a file browser on the phone itself (Astro) to delete the files- which didn't have any issues.

For some reason I'm thinking the files to delete are in the data directory, but that I am less confident on.

Answer (score 0):

go to setting->privacy->factory data reset by clicking follow procedure it will free memory 
but problem is that it erase all apps on ur phone & make sure that sd card removed. try it work for me

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, I could fix it by using adb shell, then su (obviously must have su installed, many installs don't come with it by default), then going to /data/local/tmp and deleting everything on that folder.

Very important: DON'T forget the su, otherwise you will just keep getting a permission denied

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me when trying to install a large app to my Galaxy Tab 2 tablet.  The install failed, but the app was still taking up over 1GB of space and I couldn't figure out any way to remove it within Android.  I was able to find the files and clear them out by doing the following:

1. Connected my tablet to my PC using the USB cable.
2. In the Windows popup, selected to "Open device to view files" in Windows explorer.
3. On my tablet, selected Media device (MTP).
4. 2 different locations were shown: Card and Tablet.  I clicked on Tablet.
5. I went to each folder, right clicked on it, and selected "Properties".  This showed me the Size of the files within that folder.
6. Using the method above, I was able to find the folders that were taking up the most space.  The failed install files were under "Android\obb\com.company.appname".  I used Windows Explorer to delete that particular folder.
7. When I disconnected and went back to my tablet, the 1GB space was cleared.